# The Glob (npm package) does not matches the file which name begins from dot

Tags: node.js, glob

The Glob pattern:

```
D:/WebDevelopmentProjects/InitiativeClientsProject/Example/HomePage/01-Source/Automation/ToCopy/Production/**/*
```

does not matching the file `.env.production.generated` with full path
`D:\WebDevelopmentProjects\InitiativeClientsProject\Example\HomePage\01-Source\Automation\ToCopy\Production\.env.production.generated`.

Something wrong with my Glob pattern, or some extra options for the `glob.sync()` required?
Currently, I am using only `nodir: true` option.

```js
import Glob from "glob";

Glob.sync(
  [ "D:/WebDevelopmentProjects/InitiativeClientsProject/Example/HomePage/01-Source/Automation/ToCopy/Production/**/*" ], 
  { nodir: true }
);
```

[image]

The result is everything except `.env.production.generated`:

```
[
  'D:\\WebDevelopmentProjects\\InitiativeClientsProject\\Example\\HomePage\\01-Source\\Automation\\ToCopy\\Production\\package.json',
  'D:\\WebDevelopmentProjects\\InitiativeClientsProject\\Example\\HomePage\\01-Source\\Automation\\ToCopy\\Production\\FrontServer.Dockerfile',
  'D:\\WebDevelopmentProjects\\InitiativeClientsProject\\Example\\HomePage\\01-Source\\Automation\\ToCopy\\Production\\docker-compose.yml',
  'D:\\WebDevelopmentProjects\\InitiativeClientsProject\\Example\\HomePage\\01-Source\\Automation\\ToCopy\\Production\\ssl\\SSL_Key-Production.pem',
  'D:\\WebDevelopmentProjects\\InitiativeClientsProject\\Example\\HomePage\\01-Source\\Automation\\ToCopy\\Production\\ssl\\SSL_Certificate-Production.pem'
]
```

Comment: Do you use PowerShell? I don't know the behavior on Windows but all shells on Linux and Mac I know ignore hidden files (starting with a dot) with the glob `*` and as far as I know Microsoft copied some of this behavior into PowerShell. Try `.*`. The first sentence in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) is _"Match files using the patterns the shell uses"_. The result depends on your shell.

Comment: There is also a `--dot` option for files starting with a dot.

Comment: @jabaa "Do you use PowerShell?" - maybe indirectly, to run the `npm` command. "Here is also a `--dot` option for files starting with a dot." - It has solved the problem. Thank you for the hint. Would you please to comment about it in the answer? I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most shells ignore files starting with a dot when you use the glob `*`. The npm package has `--dot` option for this case. This option includes files starting with a dot in the glob.

**Command Line Interface**

> --dot
>
> Allow patterns to match files/directories that start
> with '.', even if the pattern does not start with '.'

**Options**

> dot
>
> Include .dot files in normal matches and globstar matches. Note that an explicit dot in a portion of the pattern will always match dot files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Accept & upvote, as I promised.